# In CQ's cq:IncludeClientLib, what's the difference between theme and categories attributes?

Tags: aem, jcr

According to the [docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#<cq%3aincludeClientLib>):

**categories**

> A list of comma-separated client lib categories. This will include all Javascript and CSS libraries for the given categories. The theme name is extracted from the request.
>   Equivalent to: `com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager#writeIncludes`

**theme**

> A list of comma-separated client lib categories. This will include all theme related libraries (both CSS and JS) for the given categories. The theme name is extracted from the request. Equivalent to: `com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager#writeThemeInclude`

I am new to CQ and this looks a bit vague to me. What's the difference between these attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you had the following in the JCR:
 - /etc/clientlibs/grid
 - /etc/clientlibs/forms
 - /etc/clientlibs/tables
 - /etc/clientlibs/tables/responsive
 - /etc/clientlibs/tables/inverse

**categories** should pull in a list of un-related Client Libraries.  For instance `<cq:includeClientLib categories="grid, forms, tables" />`

**themes** should pull in distinct related Client Libraries. Or probably better described as sub-categories. For instance, `<cq:includeClientLib categories="tables" themes="inverse, responsive" />`

The difference is themes resides inside of a category.  `tables` could contain but "sub-categories" (or themes), but you have a good reason for breaking them out.  You want to use your general `tables` category on ALL your pages & designs, but certain pages would want an `inverse` display of the tables.  Or only certain pages contain `responsive` tables.

I thought CQ5.5 had better examples in the code, but CQ5.6 doesn't appear to have much OOB anymore.